# Run Java .class file from inside Java

Tags: java, file, compilation, cmd

I have a program that reads a .java file and compiles it into a .class file. Now the next step of my project is to run this .class file in java. Eventually I'll need to be able to pass it keystrokes to the Scanner class, but that's another task after I figure out this part.

Obviously I can run a cmd that will run the .class file, but I believe I lose all control of input and output of the program, both of which I need to access from the main program.

How can I run a .class file from java in a way that I'll be able to control the Scanner inputs and read outputs?

Thanks

Comment: If it uses `System.in`, you can change that with [`System#setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) - same thing with out/err.

Comment: You can use whatever Java has for spawning a process, and read/write from the stdin/out handles. But this is a really indirect way of communicating with a module; are you sure you can't restructure the program to take a string instead?

Comment: Thanks, I might be able to use that somehow. The end goal is to run a .java file, compile it, and run it with set arguments through the Scanner class. With that method I should be able to switch the input to a java runtime argument and not break the code right?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo All code I'm compiling will be utilizing the Scanner class for input. For this application I need to assume I can't change the code to change to stdin /java parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can run the .class file using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java [filename without .class]")`. For passing the keystokes you could use the input parameters in the main method or use your main app to write them to a file which can then be read by the .class file. A nother way of doing this is to run a local server to which the .class file could connect and recive keystrokes.